# sending udp message using dgram in node.js

Tags: node.js

```
const dgram = require('dgram');
var message =Buffer.from('\x53\x5a\x30\x30\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x01\x03\x01\xce\x1e');
const client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
client.send(message,8900,'192.168.178.117', function(err, bytes) {
if (err) throw err;
client.close();
});
```

When I look at the package with wireshark:
actual result:
[not correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YcVJ.png)

but thats not correct,
it should be:
[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKu32.png)

When I sent the message with netcat in linux shell like this:

```
echo -n -e "\x53\x5a\x30\x30\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x01\x03\x01\xce\x1e" | nc -u 192.168.178.117 8900
```

it is correct (as shown in second picture), but I don`t get it to work correct with node.js

Anyone sees what i`m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I had to change the Buffer to ascii, it works now.